# Packer kms_key_id for ebs volumes

Tags: amazon-web-services, packer, amazon-kms

I'm trying to use packer to build an AMI with encrypted EBS volumes (but not an encrypted root volume). The packer documentation says:

> kms_key_id (string) - The ID of the KMS key to use for boot volume encryption.
>   https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/amazon-ebs.html#kms_key_id

If I supplied a `kms_key_id` and mark the desired ebs volumes' `ami_` and `launch_block_device_mappings` as encrypted, will packer use that kms key? Or will a default CMK key be used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quickly looking into the code it looks like `kms_key_id` is only used for the encryption of the boot volume. Other `block_device_mappings` with `"encrypted": true` will be encrypted with the default EBS KMS key.